# Open multiple tabs/windows pointing to external sites with a single user click

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, popup-blocker

I want to open more than one browser tab/window when user clicked a button or link. The external tab/windows would be pointing to external sites.

I already tried different ways to accomplish this but in each case Chrome blocked tab/windows except first one. While Firefox is opening those without problem.

These are methods I already tried and got failed on Chrome. These logics are coded within click event handler (jQuery) of an anchor element. URL values are taken from anchor elements of certain class.

Method1
Try to open tabs using window.open() function with 1 second interval between each successive calls, when user clicked the link.

Method2
Open blank tabs first and after an interval change their location. Chrome, even do not allow opening more than one blank tabs.

Method3
Open a tab passing external site URL as URL parameter, then within that tab open another tab pointing to the location of URL passed in and close first opened tab. Repeat this for remaining URLs. It failed because the tab opening action within tab just opened is not an user generated action.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it solve my problem
http://www.yourdomain.com');window.open('http://www.yourdomain.com');" href="#">SAMPLE TEXT